# Model without table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, model, eloquent, relation

1. Is it possible to create model in Laravel which is not associated with table? I mean model `Meal` not connected with `meals` table, `Animal` with `animals` table etc.

   I would like to create three models: `Photo`, `Reference`, `Certificate` and relate `Reference` to `Photo` and `Certificate` to `Photo` as Polymorphic Relations. I would like to have `Reference` and `Certificate` models only for convenience and invoke method which returns relation to Photo model.
2. Is it better to pass `Relation` or `Collection` object as an argument? Which is more efficient, convenient? Sometimes I have to use closure to
   filter collections and it looks quite strange when we compare it
   with method chaining invoked on relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in your model

```
protected $table ='your table name';
```

for example if you have elephant table in your Animal model just put this code like this

```
protected $table ='elephant';
```

Comment: Ok. But you wrote about model which is connected with table. I want to connect only `Photo` model with table `photos` and then use **non-associated** model `Certificate` only to set photoable_type as `App\Certificate`. I mean **there is no** `certificate` table. Can I do it? Is it correct?